# how to check node.js application with monit

Tags: monitor, upstart

We have an app in node.js , we are using startup for starting and stoping. but we want to implement monit for monitoring the app. so what i have done is

Installed Monit.
Changed configure file .

here is my config file .

```
check host statupprogramwith address 68.178.232.100
     start "/sbin/start statupprogram"
     stop "/sbin/stop statupprogram"
     if failed port 8002 protocol HTTP
          request /
          with timeout 5 seconds
          then restart
```

I am following http://wellconsidered.be/nodejs-with-upstart-and-monit

why this message is not coming when i stop

```
  stop startupprogram
```

why this message is not coming

```
Remote Host 'startupprogram'
  status                            Connection failed
  monitoring status                 monitored
  port response time                -1.000s to 109.74.206.126:8124/ [HTTP via TCP]
  data collected                    Fri Mar 25 19:01:55 2011
```

Comment: Your fail message says different IPs and ports.. are you sure they are related?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards